# Imitating Voice vs Imitating Syntax

Tags: voice, syntax

Some advice about writing says to imitate the voice of a piece in order to learn it or to imitate the voices of multiple pieces in order to fuse them into your own. Other advice says to imitate the syntax in order to learn sentence structure.

Are voice and sentence structure linked, or are they two different things? And can you imitate one without imitating the other? Or can you learn one without learning the other?

Answer (score 2):

Syntax/sentence structure, is one *component* of the voice of a piece, so you could imitate the sentence structure but still have a different voice.

Vocabulary, tone, point of view - all these combine with syntax to form the "voice"